# Facebook Pixel returns weird results

Tags: javascript, magento, ads, facebook-pixel

I have installed the new Facebook Pixel in my website. But I get strange, inconsistant results:

- In Facebook Ads Manager, the pixel appears as active, I can see the traffic and everything...
- ... but if I check with Chrome Pixel Helper, I see that none of my events actually load: all of them return the same error message: "The Facebook Pixel code on this page didn't load, so no information was sent to Facebook";
- and back in Ads Manager, when I run a test campaign, my pixel tells me that I got a certain amount of conversions, add-to-carts, etc. And yet, this is not true: I did not receive any purchase at all!

So basically, something is messed up in my Facebook script that makes **my pixel return results that do not correspond to reality**. Would someone have an idea of the reason for this problem? Many thanks in advance.

My store is running Magento CE 1.9.0.1 and here is the Facebook-generated pixel code I have copied in `app/design/frontend/shopper/default/template/page/html/head.phtml`:

```
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
document,'script','//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');

fbq('init', '119809338361519');
fbq('track', "PageView");

    fbq('track', 'ViewContent');
    fbq('track', 'AddToCart');
    fbq('track', 'InitiateCheckout');
    fbq('track', 'Purchase', {value: '0.00', currency: 'EUR'});
    fbq('track', 'CompleteRegistration');

</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=119809338361519&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the similar issue. With these changes I resolved the issue:

```
<head>
!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
.... 
....
....
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
</head>

<script>
fbq('track', 'ViewContent');
fbq('track', 'AddToCart');
fbq('track', 'InitiateCheckout');
fbq('track', 'Purchase', {value: '0.00', currency: 'EUR'});
fbq('track', 'CompleteRegistration');
</script>
```

Summary: View the source code of the page. Ideally facebook pixel code (as provided by facebook) should be within  tags. Whereas tracking code should be outside it. Hence i have copied the tracking code directly into the body of respective page. After this I am no more getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

If you have adBlock running on your site, disable it.

Hope this helps someone